# Changing alignment of divs when they flow past each other

Tags: css

I'm wondering if there is a pure-css way of making divs change alignment when they flow past each other or "wrap" as the window resizes. Two divs on a single row, one floated left the other floated right. On smaller viewports they stack but retain their left and right alignment. I can center them on a media query like this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vrac/gcuekarx/, but the media query isn't ideal because the left-box content is of variable length and thus setting a breakpoint for the media query is only a guess.
Cheers

Html:

```
<div id="nav_row">
  <div id="left_box">Left box with variable content width xxxxxxxxxxxxx
  </div>
  <div id="right_box">Right box

  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#nav_row {
  background: blue;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

#left_box {
  background: red;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

#right_box {
  background: green;
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
  float: right;
}
```

Media query:

```
@media (min-width: 250px) and (max-width: 400px) {
  #nav_row {
    background: yellow;
  }
  #left_box {
    background: purple;
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
  }
  #right_box {
    background: teal;
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the easiest way to change alignment is to use

> FlexBox

It's so easy to change the 'wrap' using the flex-wrap.

You can see more here https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond. Unfortunately flexbox is still too recent for my audience's browser support. I should have specified that I'm looking for a "plain-vanilla" css method.

Comment: Then I think you will need to use media querys and make realy good break points, try to use breakpoint at 768px, 992px, 1200px, because super small screens are in most cases less then 768px(phones), then we have tablets from 768px, then there is some desktops from 992px and from 1200px goes large desktops